# Why is a kubernetes job neither running, succeeded or failed?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob, kubernetes-jobs

I have a job showed as incomplete:

```sh
$ kubectl get job | grep "flight-supplier-cache-import"
flight-supplier-cache-import-27290160    1/1           35s        10d
flight-supplier-cache-import-27291600    1/1           34s        9d
flight-supplier-cache-import-27293040    1/1           34s        8d
flight-supplier-cache-import-27304560    0/1           10h        10h
```

Typically the job would complete in ~35s. This last one `flight-supplier-cache-import-27304560` has been incomplete for 10hrs.

Then I saw

```sh
$ kubectl describe job flight-supplier-cache-import-27304560 | grep "Pod Statuses"
Pods Statuses:            0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
```

What does this even mean? Neither running, succeeded or failed?

Please help.

Comment: Pod status is not Job status. Can you post the complete output of `kubectl describe job flight-supplier-cache-import-27304560`.